# Dynamic binding of v-model to computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component where i'd like to iterate over elements with a computed property.

Under normal circumstances you'd do something like this:

```js
// Computed property
acquiredPrice: {
  get () {
    return value
  },
  set (value) {
    // set the value with some vuex magic
  },
},
```

And then reference it in the template like this:

```html
<v-text-field
    v-model="acquiredPrice"
>
</v-text-field>
```

And this works just as expected. However i would like to do the following

```js
// computed property
steps () {
  return [
    {
      allowed: true,
      text: 'Some question?',
      type: 'integer',
      model: this.acquiredPrice, // reference to the computed property
    },
  ]
},
```

```html
<!-- inside template -->
<template v-for="step in steps">
  <v-row
      :key="step.text"
  >
    <v-col>
        <h4>{{step.text}}</h4>
        <!-- This does not work. Only in retrieving the value -->
        <v-text-field
            v-model="step.model"
        >
        </v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

So the core issue is that when i iterate over the steps and use the step.model to reference the computed property, i loose the setter. I.e when typing into the field the setter method is never hit.

Maybe there is some way to access computed properties by string names, so i can avoid the actual value in the dict?

I.e something like (this is just pseudo code for what i want) `v-model=$computed['acquiredPrice']`

A full PoC to illustrate the issue can be seen here:

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <template v-for="step in steps">
      <v-row
          :key="step.text"
      >
        <v-col>
            <h4>{{step.text}}</h4>
            <!-- This does not work. Only in retrieving the value -->
            <v-text-field
                v-model="step.model"
            >
            </v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </template>
    <!-- This works just as expected -->
    <v-text-field
        v-model="acquiredPrice"
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'redacted',
    props: {
    },
    data: () => ({
    }),
    computed: {
      acquiredPrice: {
        get () {
          return value
        },
        set (value) {
          // set the value with some vuex magic
          // THIS IS NEVER HIT WHEN IT IS REFERENCED FROM step.model ON LINE 13
        },
      },
      steps () {
        return [
          {
            allowed: true,
            text: 'Some question?',
            type: 'integer',
            model: this.acquiredPrice,
          },
        ]
      },
    },
    components: {
    },
    methods: {
    },
    mounted () {
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you can use a watcher pattern instead with `deep: true`.

Comment: why not v-bind to  `acquiredPrice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root issue is in this line:

```js
model: this.acquiredPrice, // reference to the computed property
```

Because you are not assigning reference to `acquiredPrice` computed property into `model`, you are calling its getter and assigning value it returns...

There is nothing like `$computed` because its not needed - computed prop is just another member of your component so you can access it like `this["acquiredPrice"]` and since `this` is not available in templates, you can use a *little trick* using the method and returning `this` from it....

Whole solution:

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 10
    };
  },
  computed: {
    acquiredPrice: {
      get() {
        return this.counter;
      },
      set(value) {
        // just placeholder as we dont have Vuex here
        this.counter = value;
        console.log("Updating counter", value)
      }
    },
    steps() {
      return [{
        allowed: true,
        text: 'Some question?',
        type: 'integer',
        model: 'acquiredPrice'
      }, ]
    },
  },
  methods: {
    self() {
        return this
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ counter }}

  <div v-for="step in steps" :key="step.text">
    <h4>{{step.text}}</h4>    
    <input v-model="self()[step.model]" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed! Thank you so much for your concise and perfect answer.